# No module named keras error when I use from keras.models import load_model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
from keras.models
import load_model
```

In this code, `no module named 'keras'`
error happened.

How can I resolve it?

I already tried pip install `tensorflow`, and checked the versions of Python and `keras` but I couldn't resolve this problem.

Comment: Provide minimal reproducible example. Provide an error trace and your env (pip list env)

Answer (score 0):

As Tensorflow [Github support](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/58610) suggests, instead of keras.models; import load_model use:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
```

Alternatively according to the same ticket you might want to use [Tensorflow-cpu](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-cpu/) instead.

If you just want to install the module use:

```
import tensorflow as tf
# tf is an alias typically used for Tensorflow
```